SSR not reflecting when rendering
I am trying to implement SSR using DDA but the output result seems to not product any reflections or reflect the scene. I feel the code is correct from my knowledge of graphics at the moment and writing shaders so I am completely at a loss for what might be causing the issue.
vec3 screen_space_reflections_dda()
{
    float maxDistance = debugRenderer.maxDistance;
    vec2 texSize = textureSize(depthTex, 0);

    // World 
    vec3 WorldPos = texture(gBuffPosition, uv).xyz;
    vec3 WorldNormal = normalize(texture(gBuffNormal, uv).xyz);
    vec3 camDir = normalize(WorldPos - ubo.cameraPosition.xyz);
    vec3 worldRayDir = normalize(reflect(camDir, WorldNormal.xyz)); 
    vec3 worldSpaceEnd = WorldPos.xyz + worldRayDir * maxDistance;

    /* Get the start and end of the ray in screen-space (pixel-space) */
    // Start of ray in screen-space (pixel space)
    vec4 start = ubo.projection * ubo.view * vec4(WorldPos.xyz, 1.0);
    start.xyz /= start.w;
    start.xy = start.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
    start.xy *= texSize;

    // End of ray in pixel-space
    vec4 end = ubo.projection * ubo.view * vec4(worldSpaceEnd, 1.0);
    end.xyz /= end.w;
    end.xy = end.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
    end.xy *= texSize;
    
    vec2 delta = end.xy - start.xy;
    bool permute = false;
    if(abs(delta.x) < abs(delta.y))
    {
        // Make x the main direction 
        permute = true;
        delta = delta.yx;
        start.xy = start.yx;
        end.xy = end.yx;
    }

    float stepX = sign(delta.x); // this will be 1.0 if positive or -1.0 is negative 
    float invdx = (stepX / delta.x); 
    float stepY = delta.y * invdx; // how much to move in y for every step in x 
    vec2 stepDir = vec2(stepX, stepY) * 0.4; // apply some jitter 

    // Offset the start to prevent self-intersection
    start.xy += stepDir;
    
    // Set current to beginning of ray in screen space
    vec2 currentPixel = start.xy;
    for(int i = 0; i < int(debugRenderer.stepCount); currentPixel += stepDir, i++)
    {
        // Advance the screen-space position one step in the loop
        // Permute the currentPixel if needed
        vec2 screenPixel = permute ? currentPixel.yx : currentPixel.xy;

        // Interpolate the depth at the screen-space point DDA is currently at
        float s = (screenPixel.x - start.x) / delta.x;
        s = clamp(s, 0.0, 1.0);

        // interpolate perspective-correct z-depth http s://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~lowkl/publications/lowk_persp_interp_techrep.pdf
        float rayDepth = 1.0 / ((1.0 / start.z) + s * ((1.0 / end.z) - (1.0 / start.z)));

        // Compare depth of ray and the depth at the current fragment
        // If ray behind depth, we hit geometry; sample color
        float sampledDepth = (texelFetch(depthTex, ivec2(screenPixel.xy), 0).x); 
        float d = (rayDepth - sampledDepth);

        // depth > 0 = ray ahead of depth
        if (d > 0.0 && d < debugRenderer.thickness) {
            return texelFetch(albedo, ivec2(screenPixel), 0).rgb; // Fetch albedo for result
        }
    }
    return vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

This is my output with:
stepcount = 100,
thickness = 0.6,
maxDistance = 2.0,
Jitter = 0.4

